# Getting an explicitly set foreground color for a JButton

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jbutton

I have a custom ButtonUI class that paints the button. Before drawing the text, the paint method checks whether the button has been set a custom color in order to use that instead of UIDefaults#get("Button.foreground").

```
if ((b.getForeground() != null)) {
    colText = b.getForeground();
}
```

Having a look into the java.awt.Component class yields a problem:

```
public Color getForeground() {
    Color foreground = this.foreground;
    if (foreground != null) {
        return foreground;
    }
    Container parent = this.parent;
    return (parent != null) ? parent.getForeground() : null;
}
```

So checking the button's getForeground() against null doesn't help that much as it will return the foreground color for the component the button is placed on.

Question is: How do I check whether the button has explicitly been set a custom foreground color?

Putting a PropertyChangedListener on the button might be a solution, but I somehow think there must be a simpler way.

Comment: sorry, hit the wrong button while typing, now complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `Component` you can find the `isBackgroundSet()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Override the method and have it return this.foreground; or add a new method that returns that.

Comment: You can only do that if you are producing the Button. This may not be what he wants.